# Show that if $ X $ is regular, then for every neighborhood $U$ of $ x \in X $ there exists a neighborhood $ V $ such that $ \overline{V} \subset{U} $

Tags: general-topology

Show that if $ X $ is regular, then for every neighborhood $ U$ of $ x \in X $ there exists a neighborhood $ V $ such that $ \overline{V\mkern-0.5mu} \subset{U} $.

Given $ x \in X $ and a neighborhood $U$ of $X$, we choose $F = X-U$ closed set.
There are open disjoint $ A $ and $ B $ such that $x \in A$ , $F \subset B$ .

I need to show that $ \bar{A} \subset U $ and I know $ A \cap X-U = \emptyset$.

How can I prove that $ \bar{A} \cap (X-U) $ is empty?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\overline{A}\cap(X-U)\neq\emptyset$. Let $y\in\overline{A}\cap(X-U)$. In particular, $y\in\overline{A}$. This means that every neighborhood of $y$ intersects with $A$. But clearly, $B$ is a neighborhood of $y$ which doesn't intersect with $A$. Hence a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

As $A \subseteq X-B$ (from $A \cap B = \emptyset$) and $X-B$ is closed, we conclude that $\overline{A} \subseteq X-B$. Moreover $F \subseteq B$ implies $X-B \subseteq X-F= U$, so in all we have $\overline{A} \subseteq U$ as required.